# Passing prompt data from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First of all i know there are multiple topics about this on stackoverflow, i read most of them but i still cant figure out why the following is not working.

So i have a form like this:

```
echo "<td> <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"GET\" onsubmit=\" modifyPassword();\">
```

this is the modifyPassword function:

```
function modifyPassword(){
   var newpw=prompt("Enter a new password");
   if(newpw !== null){
   $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "admin.php",
           data: newpw,
           success: function(data)
            {
              console.log(data);
            }
            });
            }}
```

And when the form is actually submitted i want to get the value from what is typed in like this:

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

This is all in the same file.
The output of $_GET['data'] does not show anything.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

//edit, more code:
I am using multiple forms, so here is the code that handles the form:

```
}elseif (isset($_GET['Modify'])){


        echo $_GET['data'];
```

Form itself:

```
echo "<td> <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"GET\" onsubmit=\" modifyPassword();\">
                         <input type='hidden' name='counter' value=\"$count\"/> 
                         <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\" name=\"Modify\"/>
```

Function that is provided:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function modifyPassword(){

                            var newpw=prompt("Enter a new password");
                            if(newpw !== null){
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: "admin.php",
                                    data: {data: newpw}, // passing a key/value pair
                                    success: function(data)
                                    {
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }}
                        </script>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

`data: newpw,` should be `data: {data: newpw},` This will result in `$_GET['data']` being populated. In this case 'data' becomes the key, while 'newpw' is the value.

```
function modifyPassword(){
   var newpw=prompt("Enter a new password");
   if(newpw !== null){
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "admin.php",
           data: {data: newpw}, // passing a key/value pair
           success: function(data)
            {
              console.log(data);
            }
       });
   }}
```

I will argue that you should not use so many variables with the same name - just to make things less confusing during bug hunting.

Comment: Hm it still gives me NULL when i use var_dump or echo the $_GET['data]. Should i post more code or something?

Comment: I did, its not that lot more. but if i add all its a big mess :p I thought i only add thats relevant

Comment: If you're going to add more code add it to your original post, not the answer I've provided here.

Comment: Oops sorry.. Editted my own post now.  I am running this through phpstorm btw. No errors when i check firebug. and i included the library

Comment: When you watch the request/response  do you see the data being sent to PHP?

Comment: When is check the whole response its just the source code of the page.  These are the headers : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Server: PhpStorm 2016.2.1
Content-Length: 6793.

Comment: GET /Project2.2MaardanNieuw/Webpage/admin.php?counter=1&Modify=Modify HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:63342/Project2.2MaardanNieuw/Webpage/admin.php
Cookie: Phpstorm-11bbd827=98b1c139-c53f-4f27-a319-63e481c95896; PHPSESSID=5l1klgos5tpjs2a17pjnkjuq90
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

Comment: Ah, when i register a user. its gives me /Project2.2MaardanNieuw/Webpage/admin.php?name=berend&password=berend&Register=Register HTTP/1.1

Comment: So i guess its not sent with the form or something?